# Need a little help my java code

Tags: java, loops

I am teaching myself Java using Savitch's Absolute Java. I am working on the programming projects: what I am asked to do is code a game of craps. My code works overall, but I am getting an infinite loop with a portion of it. Can anybody points out what I am doing wrong? This is what I am asked to do: **If 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 is rolled on the come out roll, that number
becomes “the point.” The player keeps rolling the dice until either 7 or the point is
rolled. If the point is rolled first, then the player wins the bet. If a 7 is rolled first,
then the player loses.**

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ProgProject2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Random randomGeneratorDice1 = new Random();
Random randomGeneratorDice2 = new Random();
//int counter = 1;
int dice1, dice2, sum, winNumber = 0, lossNumber = 0;       
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++)
{
    System.out.println("Roll number " + counter + " of the dice: ");
    dice1 = randomGeneratorDice1.nextInt(6) + 1;
    dice2 = randomGeneratorDice2.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sum = dice1 + dice2;
    System.out.println("Dice1 value is: " + dice1 + " and dice2 value is: " 
                + dice2);
    System.out.println("The output of the dice roll is: " + sum);
    if ((sum == 7) || (sum == 11))
    {
        System.out.println("You win!!");
        winNumber++;
    } // end if
    else if ((sum == 2) || (sum == 3) || (sum == 12))
    {
        System.out.println("You lose!!");
        lossNumber++;
    } // end else if
    **else
    {
        System.out.println("The point!!");
        //System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);         
        //int point = sum;
        int sumElse;
        do
        {
            dice1 = randomGeneratorDice1.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dice2 = randomGeneratorDice2.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sumElse = dice1 + dice2;
            if (sumElse == sum)
            {
                System.out.println("You win!!");
                winNumber++;
            } // end inner if
            else if (sumElse == 7)
            {
                System.out.println("You lose!!");
                lossNumber++;
            } // end inner else

        } while ((sumElse != sum) || (sumElse != 7));               
    } // end else**

    } // end for loop

    System.out.println("Your total wins are: " + winNumber + " and your total "
            + "losses are: " + lossNumber);
    double winProbability = (double) winNumber / (winNumber + lossNumber);
    System.out.println("Your winning probability is: " + winProbability);

} // end main

} // end ProgProject2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
} while ((sumElse != sum) || (sumElse != 7));
```

to

```
} while ((sumElse != sum) && (sumElse != 7));
```

---

Or you can have an infinite loop, but add `break` statements (to exit the loop) in the condition bodies:

```
do {
    dice1 = randomGeneratorDice1.nextInt(6) + 1;
    dice2 = randomGeneratorDice2.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sumElse = dice1 + dice2;
    if (sumElse == sum) {
        System.out.println("You win!!");
        winNumber++;
        break;
    } // end inner if
    else if (sumElse == 7) {
        System.out.println("You lose!!");
        lossNumber++;
        break;
    } // end inner else

} while (true);
```